# Dynamic 404 Page.. kinda

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Alright, so this is what I am trying to achieve.

I want to be able to send URL data to a php file if the server returns 404.

for example:

```
example.com/stackoverflow
```

would bring up a dynamic 404 page

```
(404.php?id=stackoverflow)
```

but I am not using it for 404 in my case, I want to send the data after the domain.com/

So that I can pull from my database and display content accordingly.

I know this can be done with a small rewrite in the .htaccess, regex is just confusing for me.

I do NOT want a redirect.

```
http://example.com/datahere
```

should show the data of

```
404.php?id=datahere
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ErrorDocument` directive to redirect 404 uris to  `/404.php` something like the following :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php?id=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This will rewrite `/datahere` to `/404.php?id=datahere` ( `/datahere` will show you the contents of `/404.php?id` ) .

Note that the above directive doesn't work on apache versions bellow  2.4 as the mod-rewrite variable `%{REQUEST_URI}` is treated as plain text not as a variable on lower versions.

On apache 2.2  you could use mod-rewrite to rewrite non-existent requests to 404 . Use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /404.php?id=$1 [L]
```